# YARN Kerberos issue for long runing applications

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

We are trying to setup a long running YARN application that should run beyond the lifetime of the delegation tokens[7 days] in Hadoop cluster with Yarn cluster mode.

As per the link [YARN Security](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YarnApplicationSecurity.html) we have done below steps

- Uploaded keytab to HDFS in YARN client
- passed the keytab path and principal information from the YARN client to ApplicationMaster.
- Downloaded the keytab to the node in which Application Master runs
- After 75% of token[HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN] expiry a new token is created by below code

  ```
  UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(props.getUserName(), keytabPath);
  if (UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled()) {
          Credentials creds = UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser().getCredentials();
          final Token<?> tokens[] = fs.addDelegationTokens("app", creds);
          for(Token<?> token : creds.getAllTokens()) {
              log.info(" " +token);
              if(token != null && token.getKind().toString().equals(HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN)) {
                  DelegationTokenIdentifier id = (DelegationTokenIdentifier)token.decodeIdentifier();         
                  long diff = id.getMaxDate() - id.getIssueDate();
                  long maxDiff = Math.round(Long.valueOf(diff).doubleValue() * RELOGIN_PERCENT);
                  reloginTimestamp = id.getIssueDate() + maxDiff;
                  issueTimestamp = id.getIssueDate();
                  log.info("expiry date " + id.getMaxDate());
                  log.info(RELOGIN_PERCENT*100 +"% of expiry date " + reloginTimestamp);
              }
          }
          allTokens = IgniteYarnUtils.createTokenBuffer(creds);
      }
  ```

We are getting below exception after some time

```
18/07/16 17:27:07 INFO client.ConfiguredRMFailoverProxyProvider: Failing over to rm116
18/07/16 17:27:07 INFO retry.RetryInvocationHandler: Exception while invoking allocate of class ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl over rm116 after 645 fail over attempts. Trying to fail over after sleeping for 1996ms.
java.net.ConnectException: Call failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor45.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:791)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:731)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1508)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1441)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:230)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.allocate(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:256)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.allocate(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.AMRMClientImpl.allocate(AMRMClientImpl.java:277)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.async.impl.AMRMClientAsyncImpl$HeartbeatThread.run(AMRMClientAsyncImpl.java:224)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:530)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:494)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:648)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:744)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$3000(Client.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1480)
        ... 12 more
```

Kindly requesting your guidance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Start with enabling the Kerberos & security config debug traces `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` plus `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext`

Comment: Also set env variable `HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG` to true.